# Can I validate business data during an Azure AD B2C custom sign up process?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We are looking into Azure AD B2C as a general identity management solution for our SaaS services.

One scenario we need to support is around distribution of pre-paid (stored value) payment cards, sold in stores or offered by other 3rd parties to customers. The customer gets the card with a PIN or one time registration code, and with that they can sign up to the cardholder portal, a web application / native app that allows them to view card history, balances and so on.

The sign up process needs to eventually identify the card as a custom claim, but also needs to validate the supplied code right there and then. The user needs to be able to go to the cardholder portal, click 'sign up' and be presented with input fields for the basic info plus the PIN/ reg code. On submit, the PIN/reg code needs to be validated.

Can Azure AD B2C support this type of scenario? Can the UI be completely custom? Are there any pricing implications to this? Also....is there anyway of having the native version of the app have a completely native version of the UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can configure this type of validation for new users signing up using [Azure AD B2C Custom Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview-custom).  Custom policies allow you to define your own policy rather than using the built-in set.  Specifically for your case, you'll be able to validate user data given at sign up with your own API.

Fair warning, custom policies can be complex to configure properly.